# Is dream interpretation on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I need an interpretation from religious point of view. Is dream interpretation on-topic on this site?

It is not in [the on-topic list](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). And I could not find [anything 'dream' related in help center search](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=dream).

So, I am not sure if 'dream interpretation' has not been discussed or is simply considered off-topic.

Comment: Do you mean like: "I had this dream. What does it mean?" Or do you mean: "What does X denomination teach about dream interpretation?" The former probably won't fly because of [our pastoral advice policy](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/255/pastoral-advice-questions).

Comment: I was referring to the former one. I got it now, it can not be on-topic. Thanks.

Comment: Some of us might have an opinion [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room). You can post about it there.

Comment: BTW, thank you for consulting the help center, a site search, and a meta post, before actually posting. A+ for research effort.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Questions here need to be ones that can have definitive answers, backed up with evidence, reason and references. How could anyone possibly interpret a dream definitively and back it up like that?

Answer (score 3):

We cannot interpret dreams by taking help from the Bible. In the Bible God gave meaningful and prophetic dreams to people but God alone knows the meaning. For instance, Daniel could interpret dreams but we don't know how he did it. Sometimes Daniel even said that he did not know the meaning and he had to ask God to give him the interpretations. So only God knows the meaning of your dream.